# Update all realmList element in java

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

is it possible to update a column in all element of realmList
in other words, can do this in realm

```
update TableX where column1=10 set(column1) values(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RealmResults<TableX> results = realm.where(TableX.class).equalTo("column1", 10).findAll();
for(TableX tableX : results) { // since 0.89.0+, previously for(int i = results.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    tableX.setColumn1(0);
}
```

Comment: It's not so bad if you do it on a background thread, although I do admit it creates proxy objects which can trigger GC which is sad. There is an issue tracking it but it's not in yet